# Unknown chipset drm failed after grub

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, nouveau, drm

I have been receiving this error every time I try to try Ubuntu or install it. I boot it in non uefi mode ( if its in uefi the screen is just blank) and choose my language. I pick an option and this happens every time. GPU is geforce 970 gaming from MSI and CPU is i7 4790. Please help.

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSyfI.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Intel integrated graphics in BIOS (your CPU has another GPU inside it).

Or maybe newer Ubuntu with newer kernel has default drivers that support this GPU from start.

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/266059

Comment: You are amazing thank you so much. Disabling intel graphics worked.